# In Eclipse: Could not find or load main class org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG

Tags: eclipse, testng

**Configuration**

I have version 2019-12 (4.14.0) of Eclipse (having recently upgraded from 2019-03) with the following plugins installed (amongst others):

```
TestNG 6.14.3.201902250526
TestNG M2E (Maven) Integration (Optional) 6.14.3.201902250526
TestNG P2 Features 6.14.3.r201802240500
```

Eclipse is running against `jdk1.8.0_152`.

In Eclipse, my Java Build Path includes `testng-6.14.3`.  I've tried to match the Eclipse plugin version against the version using in the project.

Under `Properties -> TestNG` I have all the default settings.  There is no setting here for "Use Project TestNG.jar".

**What Works**

When I run tests from the command line with Gradle they all pass with no issue.

There are no complile errors showing in Eclipse.

**What Does Not Work**

When I run a test from Eclipse (by right clicking on a class) the console shows:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG
```

It appears I need a copy of `testng-remote.jar`.  Should this have been installed as part of the plug-in, or am I meant to have included that in my `build.gradle` as a dependency?

Why can't I run tests from Eclipse?  Do I need to install something further to resolve this error?

**What I have Tried**

I have tried removing and re-installing the TestNG plugin.

Comment: -Dtestng.eclipse.verbose Add this in VM arguments in testNG runconfiguration. It may give some info. Ideally plugin should pick up testng version from the class path if available.

Comment: @RahulL But testng-remote.jar isn't on the classpath.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you hit the bug https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=558495 in Windows.
I reverted my version back to 2019-09 because of it.

The bug causes jars which should be on the classpath not to be on the classpath.  This affects projects with long classpaths.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try adding it in your build.gradle.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "io.spring.gradle:dependency-management-plugin:1.0.3.RELEASE"
        classpath group: 'org.testng', name: 'testng', version: '6.8.+'
    } }
```

Change the testng version as per your usage.

Comment: Ok, How you are running it in eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

I don't remember such problem for gradle but it looks similar to the problem with testing on maven(with auto-build turned off). The soultion is to rebuild project (for maven it ia alt +f5) and because of such rebuilding - cache is updated.

Comment: Thanks, but this didn't help

Answer (score 0):

You have [detailed TestNG gradle tutorial](https://www.seleniumeasy.com/testng-tutorials/using-testng-with-gradle)

> By default, Gradle will run all tests that it detects, which it does by inspecting the compiled test classes. When we specify useTestNG(), Gradle scans for all the methods annotated with @Test and execute them.
>
> Example 1. Below is the basic configuration for the 'test' task
>
> ```
> plugins {
>     id 'java'
> }    
> group 'com.test'
> version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'    
> sourceCompatibility = 1.8    
> repositories {
>     mavenCentral()
> }    
> dependencies {
>     compile group: 'org.testng', name: 'testng', version: '6.14.3'
> }    
> test {
>     useTestNG()
> }
> ```

For [Gradle](https://testng.org/doc/download.html) use testCompile dependencies:

> ```
> repositories {
>     jcenter()
> }     
> dependencies {
>     testCompile 'org.testng:testng:6.10'
> }
> ```

For specific version you have options,

1. Install from update site

> - Select Help / Install New Software...
> - Enter the update site URL in "Work with:" field:
> - Update site for release: http://dl.bintray.com/testng-team/testng-eclipse-release/.
> - Make sure the check box next to URL is checked and click Next.
> - Eclipse will then guide you through the process.
> - You can also install older versions of the plug-ins here. Note that the URL's on this page are update sites as well, not direct download links.

2. Build TestNG from source code

   > you can download the source and build the distribution yourself:

> ```
>   git clone git://github.com/cbeust/testng.git
>   cd testng
>   ./build-with-gradle
> ```

Comment: Does this relate to running tests from Eclipse? It's working from command line running Gradle.

Comment: @WW.actually Eclipse and TestNG have installations issues, how did you install TestNG, I don't find it in latest Eclipse marketplace?